# How Are Conditional Breakpoints Typically Implemented?

Tags: windows, debugging, x86, breakpoints

In debuggers, for example, Ollydbg, how are conditional breakpoints typically implemented? I don't quite understand how the debugger could perform checks before pausing.

Comment: 1) What makes you think, that it doesn't pause to perform a check? 2) Why is this question tagged with C++? It doesn't have anything C++-specific.

Comment: It doesn't, it adds a normal breakpoint, does the test and continues if the test fails.

Comment: x86 supports conditional breakpoints through a number of [debug registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register). I don't know whether Ollydbg uses them (it probably does). Conditional breakpoints can also be implemented using unconditional breakpoints and performing the checks in the breakpoint handler.